# Why am i getting this error when am creating a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating a new table, with various data type, one them in binary(n). When I execute the statement, I end up with the following

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to binary is not allowed, use CONVERT function.

My question: why do I get this error, when there is no data to convert, I am just creating a table?

```
Create Table EMP.DETAILS
       (
       ID INT NOT NULL,
       TYPE INT,
       Created datetime2,
       Key_No varchar(5),
       Batch_IN INT,
       UN_ID BINARY(1) not null default '',
       Source INT,
       SITE CHAR(1)
       )
```

When I execute the above statement, I get the error mentioned above, But it directs me to the `CREATE TABLE` line of the code.

Comment: lets see your create statement

Comment: if you are creating by script, please post it here

Comment: Seriously, how are we supposed to help without seeing your create statement?

Comment: Sorry about that, will be adding the script shortly.

Comment: I would guess it is the default value which is not in binary but a carchar.

Comment: The error says "Implicit conversion **from data type varchar to binary is not allowed**". You are trying to assign a default varchar character to a binary here: `UN_ID BINARY(1) not null default ''`.

Comment: It need to end with "UN_ID BINARY(1) NOT NULL" ?

Comment: @TanmoyDB No, the problem is that `''` is not a binary, it's a `char datatype, give a default value that is of the same datatype as your column

Answer (score 3):

The error says "Implicit conversion from data type varchar to binary is not allowed". You are trying to assign a default varchar character to a binary here:

```
UN_ID BINARY(1) not null default ''
```

If you absolutely need a default value for a binary column, you can set it directly as something like `0x00`:

```
UN_ID BINARY(1) not null default 0x00
```

That will basically set your default to 0. You can also set it to an integer value:

```
UN_ID BINARY(1) not null default 0
```

And finally, if you absolutely need to to be an empty string, you can find the binary representation of `''` with the following `SELECT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(binary, '')
```

I'm pretty sure it's just 0, though.

Depending on what that column is being used for, though, it might be better suited as a `tinyint`, `char(1)`, or something similar, rather than a `binary(1)`.